Echarts saveImageAs to download only one chart for connected charts
I have a code similar to the following, and the two charts are connected. But when I download the images, I will get both charts in one image. How do I have the saveImageAs feature to have the same functionality as when the two charts are not connected.
const chart1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart1'));
const option1 = {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart 1',
    left: 'center',
  },
  grid: {
    show: true,
    top: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Apples'],
    bottom: 0,
  },
  xAxis: {
    data: ['8:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '18:00', '20:00']
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Apples',
      type: 'line',
      data: [10, 35, 20, 13, 12, 18, 41]
    },
    {
      name: 'Bananas',
      type: 'line',
      data: [20, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 1]
    }
  ],
    toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  }
};

const chart2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart2'));
const option2 = {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart 2',
    left: 'center',
  },
  grid: {
    show: true,
    top: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Apples'],
    bottom: 0,
  },
  xAxis: {
    data: ['8:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '18:00', '20:00']
  },
  yAxis: [{}],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Apples',
      type: 'line',
      data: [25, 5, 17, 11, 33, 32, 2]
    },
    {
      name: 'Bananas',
      type: 'line',
      data: [1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 11]
    }
  ],
  dataZoom: [
  ],
    toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  }
};

// https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.connect
chart1.setOption(option1);
chart2.setOption(option2);
chart1.group = 'group1';
chart2.group = 'group1';
echarts.connect('group1');


Here's a codepen - need to add the saveImageAs toolbox to show the saveAs button.

You can add the toolbox option to both and split in 2 groups like this:
toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {
        title: 'Save as Image',
        name: 'chart{1 or 2}',
        pixelRatio: 2
      }
    }
  }

chart1.setOption(option1);
chart2.setOption(option2);
chart1.group = 'group1';
chart2.group = 'group2';
echarts.connect('group1');
echarts.connect('group2');



but this will disconnect the two charts. I want them connected because I want them to have a common x-axis, and when user changes x range in one chart, it should affect the other chart.
